# Oracle SQL To compare 1 or 2 or more dates to be within a given period

Tags: oracle, date

I have a scenario where I need to compare 2 or more dates for given period. 
I'm able to succeed when comparing 1 date to a period using between function. But challenge is when I have 2 dates to compare in parallel, getting single row sub query error

```
select A
from ORDER
where Date1 between sysdate and (sysdate-10)
```

Above query works fine for single date, please help to get a solution when I have Date 1 and Date 2 and need to compare against the same period (sysdate and (sysdate-10)) and I may have more than 2 dates as well.

Thanks
Shankar

Comment: `select A
from ORDER
where Date1 between sysdate and (sysdate-10) 
and Date2 between sysdate and (sysdate-10)`?

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt help for me as Date 1 and Date 2 are in same column of table and I may have more than 2 dates as well to compare. The output is expected to compare one of D1/ D2/D3.... is within the range of given period of sysdate and (sysdate-10)

Comment: You have posted a very cryptic question - in that it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Please post a sample of your table structure and data (preferably using a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4)) and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a proper description of your tables or the data they contain, it is difficult to know what you want.

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT A
FROM   ORDER
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN datecolumn BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 AND SYSDATE THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried modifiy your query for my scenario and getting an exception "ORA-00913: too many values" when tried with 2 dates. For 1 date it works fine                                                   SELECT sysdate
FROM   dual
GROUP BY sysdate
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN (select sysdate, (sysdate+1) from dual) BETWEEN SYSDATE - 10 
AND SYSDATE+10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) > 0

Comment: No further thoughts because your explanation of what you want is very confusing - if you had a clear example of what your data is and what you expect then you might get more help.